# How to run OWASP Dependency Check for an Angular project?

Tags: security, dependencies, owasp

I'm trying to use this in an Angular project:

https://owasp.org/www-project-dependency-check/

We use the Database server approach explained in https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/data/database.html in all our builds, but I been unable to trigger this analysis for the Angular project.

The official documentation offers this:

https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/analyzers/nodejs.html

Alas, I could not figure out how to use for the angular build. I have also tried the command below with no success either.

```
$ npm audit
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have installed OWASP Dependency Checker and have added it to your system path:

1. **cd** into {the Angular project directory}
2. run **ng build**
3. Then run **dependency-check.bat --project {project name} --scan .\node_modules --out {target directory} -f JSON -f HTML**

Comment: Thank you! I am no longer involved with that project, but appreciate your response. Hopefully it will help someone else!